# Does "for" change anything when coupled with "except"?

Tags: prepositions

> All the regions, **except (except for)** region B, are experiencing high average waiting times.

In the highlighted part of the sentence above, does including (or omitting) *for* change anything? If it isn't needed, why do many writers include it?

Comment: Your second question surely depends on whether *regions* is singular or plural. Even *all* on its own is plural (eg "All are welcome"). That question would be closed, so I've removed it. We don't do proof-reading, so it's necessary to ask why something is done, not whether it's correct.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I am comparing regions of a given country. In this case, should "All the regions" be treated as singular or plural?

Comment: Is *regions* singular or plural? Is *all* singular or plural? That part of your question can be answered with a dictionary, I'm afraid and is not suitable for this site.

Comment: A dictionary search just made me realize that was indeed a dumb question. Thanks @AndrewLeach!